# WBAdmin command not recognized when elevated in CreateProcessAsUser Command prompt

Tags: windows, winapi, batch-file, cmd

What is causing the command prompt to not be able to recognize the WBAdmin program?

In non elevated command prompt, I was able to use the WBAdmin. It also works when I started the elevated command prompt.

In my program I got a usertoken by using LogonUser function and took the linkedtoken from it, with elevated access. With CreateProcessAsUser I tried to spawn a command prompt with Elevated status. In that command prompt I wasn't able to start WBAdmin program. It said the command wasn't recognized.

> C:\Windows\system32>wbadmin get status
>
> 'wbadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I started my program as a service and it launches a cmd window in my current desktop. I also have noticed that in the environment settings are different than on my currently logged in account.

The differences are:

In CreateProcessAsUser Command prompt

> APPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
>
> LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
>
> TEMP=C:\Windows\TEMP
>
> TMP=C:\Windows\TEMP
>
> USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Default

In normal user logged in with windows login screen

> APPDATA=C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming
>
> LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\pta\AppData\Local
>
> TEMP=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp
>
> TMP=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp
>
> USERPROFILE=C:\Users\

The CreateProcessAsUser command prompt is missing following variables

> HOMEDRIVE - HOMEPATH - LOGONSERVER - PATHTEXT - USERDOMAIN

Does it mean the user profile is not loaded properly? I have used the following line to login as user:

```
LogonUser('username', 'domain', 'password', LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, hUserToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

- What OS?
- On my windows 8 64 bit machine I can duplicate your results from a 32 bit CMD
  prompt.
- Works fine from a 64 bit CMD prompt.
- %windir%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe is 32 bit CMD.exe
- %windir%\System32\cmd.exe is 64 bit CMD.exe

Comment: I am running windows 64bit in a virtual machine. I have tried using both cmd prompts ( 32-bit and 64-bit). It still gives me same result back.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it did not work is, because the program started the 32-bit CMD.exe.
Program itself is 32-bit and so it will start 32-bit processes by default. That is why Windows redirected me to Syswow64 folder where 32-bit CMD.exe exists.

To disable this redirection I used this function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743%28VS.85%29.aspx