# C# Start Process: The system cannot find the file specified even though it should

Tags: c#, process

I'm looking to start a process running wbadmin.

When I open a commandline and type "wbadmin" it works from anywhere.
wbadmin.exe is located in C:\Windows\System32

But when I try to start a process in my c# app I always get the error:

> The system cannot find the file specified

Here is my code:

```cs
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("wbadmin.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

var process = Process.Start(info);

var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

When I run the same with "explorer.exe" it works just fine.

Not sure what I can do. Would appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks

Comment: No repro. The code just runs and returns the help text

Comment: that's strange. What could be causing the issue then? As i said it works for me if i just type "wbadmin" in the commandline

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS perhaps? In that case calls to `System32` are redirected to the WOW64 folder.

Comment: Not sure, I have a 64 bit architecture, Are there different versions for wbadmin depending on the architecture?

Comment: Can you try by giving the parameter as 'wbadmin' instead of 'wbadmin.exe'

Comment: any x64 windows has two versions of all it's dlls & core exes, one under the `system32` directory & it contains their x64 version, and the other under the `WOW64` folder & it contains their x32 version
just set your project build type to x64 this would insure that you run the `wbadmin` that is inside the `system32` folder

Comment: You can check your project settings to find out. I bet it's *not* set to x64. Perhaps it's Any CPU with Prefer 32-bit. In any case, `wbadmin` can only be found in `c:\windows\system32`. It doesn't exist in `%windir%\SysWOW64\`, which is the System folder seen by 32-bit applications

Comment: Change your project to target x64 instead of Any CPU or x86. [This possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852603/wbadmin-command-not-recognized-when-elevated-in-createprocessasuser-command-prom) shows you can disable redirection but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So what would i have to do to make it run on x64 and x32 bit architectures?

Comment: Ok i can confirm when i changed my target architecture from any cpu to x64 it worked. But how can i support both architectures? Or would it just work on 32 bit systems because it looks in the right directory then

Comment: Clear the `Prefer 32 bit` checkbox. This will cause the application to run as a x64 app in x64 systems and 32-bit in 32-bit systems. You

Comment: What i still dont understand is, why it did not work when i specified the full path to the wbadmin.exe. Then it should have worked or am i forgetting something?
Where can i clear the preference for 32bit?@PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 2):

`explorer.exe` is under `C:\Windows`, not under `System32`.
As a solution, try to give the full path to `wbadmin.exe`: `C:\Windows\System32\wbadmin.exe`

Comment: That doesn't matter, the executable is in the path. The code runs just fine

Comment: Maybe he removed it from the path var.

Comment: `wbadmin` is in System32, not Windows. If that folder wasn't in the path there would be a *lot* of errors

Comment: Tried it just to be sure, but no, it gives the same error. How can it be that it works if i type it in the commandline

Comment: `wbadmin` just prints a text then terminates it's execution, when you run it from `C#`, it will open a console, print the text, and hence the text was printed, `wbadmin` will exit and the console disappears. It works, but you don't see the effect.

Comment: @Damian-TeodorBeleș Not on my end. I get an exception saying:"The system cannot find the file specified"